# Error when using pg_restore to restore database in docker compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, pg-restore

I ran the  following commands to create the dump file

```
sudo docker-compose up -d db
sudo docker exec –i container_name pg_dump –username username database_name > desired_path/dump.sql
```

And then I added the file to an existing volume in the `docker-compose.override.yml` file

```yml
version: '3.7'  
services:  
  db:  
    container_name: seqdb-db-container  
    volumes:  
      - ./dump.sql:path_to_volume_used_by_container  
    ports:  
      - 5432:5432
```

Finally I run

```
sudo docker exec –i container_name psql –username username database_name < path_to_dump_file
```

and I get the following error:

```
pg_restore: [archiver] input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql.
```

I want to use `docker exec pg_restore` without installing `psql`. Is there a solution to this or did I mount my volume incorrectly?

Answer (score 3):

From the [pgdump docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-pgdump.html):

> -F format
> --format=format
> Selects the format of the output. format can be one of the following:
>
> > p
> > plain
> > Output a plain-text SQL script file (the default).

So the default output format for `pg_dump` is a plain-text SQL file (which it appears you expect because you call the output `dump.sql`)

Now from the [docs for pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-pgrestore.html)

> pg_restore is a utility for restoring a PostgreSQL database from an archive created by pg_dump in one of the non-plain-text formats.

So the error, `input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql`, should be expected based on your actions. `pg_restore` does not support restoring plain-text dumps - to restore those you should use `psql` (as per the error).

The quick solution is to request a non-plain-text format when using `pg_dump` (e.g. `--format=custom`). However I am a little confused by your reluctance to use `psql`?

Comment: I upvoted, would irl suggest always taking full dumps in archive format. You can not filter which objects to restore when using plain text dumps.